# Not returning a count number for filled array

Tags: php, arrays, count

```
$arrg = array();
if( str_word_count( $str ) > 1 ) {
    $input_arr = explode(' ', $str);
    die(print_r($input_arr));
    $count = count($input_arr);
    die($count);
```

above is part of a function.
when i run i get;

```
Array (
    [0] => luke
    [1] => snowden
    [2] => create
    [3] => develop
    [4] => web
    [5] => applications
    [6] => sites
    [7] => alse
    [8] => dab
    [9] => hand
    [10] => design
    [11] => love
    [12] => helping
    [13] => business
    [14] => thrive
    [15] => latest
    [16] => industry
    [17] => developer
    [18] => act
    [19] => designs
    [20] => php
    [21] => mysql
    [22] => jquery
    [23] => ajax
    [24] => xhtml
    [25] => css
    [26] => de
    [27] => montfont
    [28] => award
    [29] => advanced
    [30] => programming
    [31] => taught
    [32] => development
    [33] => years
    [34] => experience
    [35] => topic
    [36] => fully
    [37] => qualified
    [38] => electrician
    [39] => city
    [40] => amp
    [41] => guilds
    [42] => level )
```

Which im expecting;

run this however and nothing is returned:

```
$arrg = array();
if( str_word_count( $str ) > 1 ) {
    $input_arr = explode(' ', $str);
    //die(print_r($input_arr));
    $count = count($input_arr);
    die($count);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
die($count);
```

Kills your script with `$count` (an integer) as an [exit code](http://php.net/exit).

You'll want:

```
die((string) $count);
```

(Or comparable.)

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php (same as die()):

> If status is a string, this function
>   prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer , that value
>   will also be used as the exit status.
>   Exit statuses should be in the range 0
>   to 254, the exit status 255 is
>   reserved by PHP and shall not be used.
>   The status 0 is used to terminate the
>   program successfully.

Comment: Arguably this is worded wrong, isn't it? "Will also be" should be "will be". :)

Comment: You should pass that on to the php documentation team, eh?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. Is it doing this because $count is an integer, I wonder? What happens if you die(strval($count))?

Answer (score 2):

`die()` will not print the argument if it is numeric, it'll use it as exit status code instead.

The problem is only your debugging technique... :o)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to output $count? at the moment you kill your scrippt with $count as errorcode. simly do

```
die(print($count));
```

to get what you want.

Comment: This is actually a pretty neat solution, since `print` returns `1`, so after printing, `die();` still gets an error code to work with. Of course, this is debugging code, so it's not as useful as it could be, but the construct in general is worth keeping in mind. +1

Answer (score 0):

Integer parameter to die is used as exit code of the process (die is equivalent to exit). Just check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).